# How can I create a Windows Docker Container that hosts a SSH server that does not require ANY authentication?

Tags: windows, docker, authentication, ssh

I want to create a Windows Docker container that hosts a SSH server that does not require **any** form of authentication. This container will run in an enclosed system and is just there for dev purposes (I know this is unsafe and bad practice).

This is what the Dockerfile currently looks like:

```sh
# escape = `

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

USER ContainerAdministrator

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

RUN Set-Service -Name wuauserv -StartupType Manual; `
  Start-Service -name wuauserv; `
  Get-WindowsCapability -Online | Where-Object Name -like 'OpenSSH.Server*' | Add-WindowsCapability -Online; `
  Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'; `
  Start-Service sshd

EXPOSE 22
```

Following along the [OpenSSH Server configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration) from Microsoft I was able to create a user that can connect to the SSH server that is hosted inside the container via the `password-based` authentication method. However, I want users to be able to connect to the container without the `password-based` or `key-based` authentication method (or any other method of authentication, if there is one).

In the `sshd_config` of the SSH server at `$env:ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config` I tried setting the `PasswordAuthentication` and `PubkeyAuthentication` to `no`, but I got the error `Permission denied (keyboard-interactive)`.

I also tried setting the `KbdInteractiveAuthentication` to `no` based on the [ssh config options](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config) linked by the Microsoft documentation. I also tried setting `PasswordAuthentication` to `yes` and `PermitEmptyPasswords` to `yes`, so at least users (like the `ContainerAdministrator`) without a password could connect without authentication, but this config setting also resulted in the error `Permission denied (keyboard-interactive)`.

---

Is it possible to create a a Windows Docker Container that hosts a SSH server that does not require ANY authentication? How do I have to change the SSH config file / Dockerfile?